# get any 2 columns of Choice using phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php
            $name=$_FILES['u_file']['tmp_name'];
                try {
                    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($name);
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($name);
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
                }
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
                $rowData= $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row );
            while(list($rno,$atten)=each($rowData[0]))
                echo"{$rno} -> {$atten} <br/>";
            }
        ?>
```

I`m using the above code to print details of a particular column. Is it possible to print details of any 2 columns in the above code?
For eg, If I want prints rows belonging to column C and E what should be argument in the rangeToArray Fucntion.

I`m Learning php. Is there any material/documentation for PhpExcel? Or any site that gives description of the various methods and what they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API docs (found in /Documentation/API, or available online at http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.html ) give details of all the classes/methods available in PHPExcel

The rangeToArray() method accepts a standard Excel-style range as a string, with a colon separating the top-left and bottom-right cells of the range (e.g. `A1:B2` or `A1:A65535`)

**EDIT**

```
$rowDataA = ;
$rowDataE = $sheet->rangeToArray('E2:E' . $highestRow);

$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator(
    PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::flattenArray(
        $sheet->rangeToArray('A2:A' . $highestRow)
    ), 
    'cellA'
);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator(
    PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::flattenArray(
        $sheet->rangeToArray('E2:E' . $highestRow)
    ), 
    'cellE'
);
foreach($mi as $details) {
echo $details['cellA'], ' - ', $details['cellE'], '<br />';
}
```

if you want to use rangeToArray to get the values:

or

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    $cellA = $sheet->getCell('A' . $row )->getValue();
    $cellE = $sheet->getCell('E' . $row )->getValue();
    echo "{$cellA} -> {$cellE} <br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hi,can please give a sample code for printing columns of our choice.. Eg Column A and Column E only.

Comment: $rowDataA its holds the value of multidimensional array am i correct about this if i am is the code in my question after $rowData complex?

Comment: Sorry but I cant find info about getCallValue in the site you showed Please can you put the link